# calling batch file with semicolon in parameters from cygwin

Tags: windows, batch-file, cygwin

I need to call a batch file from inside CYGWIN however one of it's parameters is a path-like string containing semicolons. Normally in windows command line one could enclose that parameter in quotes  (which would need to be trimmed later on). However this approach doesn't wok in cygwin

Example batch (echoes first 3 parameters)

```
echo %1 
echo %2
echo %3
```

Windows cmd call

```
file.bat "a;b"  c
```

Ouput

```
 "a;b"
 c
 empty
```

Cygwin call

```
 ./file.bat "a;b" c
```

Output

```
 a
 b
 c
```

Comment: I would try to escape one pair of quotes like `./file.bat "\"a;b\"" c`. So the batch parser gets also one pair of them

Comment: This was the first thing I've tried and the result is at least weird. The first parameter is then echoed as "\"a and second as b\"". After this I've came to the conclusion that I do not understand how CYGWIN passes parameters to bat script at all.

Comment: As I know that script parameters in windows can be separated by either a space, comma or semicolon, I've tried calling the script like ./test.bat "a; b" c and the result is as expected first echo printing out "a; b". Why does it work with the space?

Comment: OK, I swear it is working as intended if I put a space anywhere inside those quotes.

Comment: Then you could use `./file.bat "a;b " c` and in your batch file `echo %~1` to strip the quotes

Comment: Yop, that is what I am using right now. However I am still curious why is it working like that

Comment: Why not simply escape it using `\;`? That's what you'd do in Bash and that's what you have to do with the classic `find ... -exec ... \;` ... which means the semicolon gets passed on to `find` rather than being interpreted by Bash itself. You just have to be aware that this way when you write `\;` Bash _passes it on_ and the receiving end gets to see a single `;` instead of the `\;` you typed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Including space anywhere inside quotes will ensure that parameter with semicolon or comma is passed correctly. Although I have to admit that I do not understand this behavior whatsoever, it seems to be working flawlessly.

```
./file.bat "a;b " c
```

Output

```
"a;b"
c
```

As @jeb mentioned in his comment, enclosing quotes can be trimmed by accessing parameter variable like this

```
 %~1
```

Answer (score 1):

Recent battles with quoting led me to another technique.

Create a temporary batch file  and pass it to cmd. (I used "filex.bat" in this example).

```
echo 'call file.bat "a;b" c' > filex.bat ; cmd /c filex.bat ; rm filex.bat
```